# c# - Why can I alter my constructed link list before a while loop, but not after it?

Tags: c#, while-loop, linked-list

So I created my own version of a linked list in C# and one of the methods I'm using is removing the last element from the list. After some fooling around trying to get this to work, I realized that for some reason my code does some funny stuff when trying to remove the last element.

Here is my code for the linked list:

```
class Node
{
  public Node next;
  public int data;
}

class LinkedL 
{
  private Node head;
  //Methods...
}
```

After creating a linked list consisting of 10, 1223, 53, 93, 2830, and 93, I wrote a function within my LinkedL class called Popback that removes the last element of the linked list, in this case 93.

In the following PopBack code, I purposely added a line to reset the temp.next.next to be null before the while loop and it does what I would want it to do had the list head been 10, 1223, and 53, returning 10, 1223. The while loop doesn't seem to do anything though.

```
public void PopBack()
{
  if (head == null) { return; }

  Node temp = head;
  temp.next.next = null; //this is the added line

  while (temp.next != null)
  {
    temp = temp.next;
  }

  temp = null;                
}
```

However, if I were to remove that line, it goes through the while loop but even after setting the updated temp to be null, the list (head) doesn't change. I have a similar function to this where I add an element to the end of the linked list and that works just fine. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Why do you set temp to null? It runs out of scope. Unless there is some big missunderstanding, there is no point to even doing that. Also why is "head" defined outside of the Function and not a Function Argument? Are you using a static/class cope variable?

Comment: Because after the while loop, temp = 93->null and I want to set it to temp = null to remove that last element.

Comment: @DaveWashington : can you be more clear on the purpose of  adding `temp.next.next to be null`

Comment: My main reason for adding the temp.next.next line was to see if my problem was with the while loop or trying to set temp to be null. Adding the line did what I expected it to do, removing all elements from temp.next.next to the end of the list. Had I used temp = null instead, it would've made head = null like I want it to. Using it after the while loop however, it doesn't seem to affect head at all.

Comment: @DaveWashington: That is not, never was and propably never will be how you remove a element from any form of list. `var b = a; b = null;` would not affect a, would it? MarcinJuraszek gave you the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about it the wrong way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `temp` to null does just that - sets `temp` variable to point at `null`. It does not change what the `Next` property of the previous element points at.

To do what you want and remove the last element you need to modify the second-to-last `Node`s `Next` to point at `null`:

```
public void PopBack()
{
    if (head == null) { return; }
    if (head.Next == null) { head = null; return; }

    Node temp = head;
    while (temp.next.next != null)
    {
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    temp.next = null;
}
```

**Update**

In one of your comments you mentioned:

> Had I used temp = null instead, it would've made head = null like I want it to. Using it after the while loop however, it doesn't seem to affect head at all.

That's not true.

```
public void PopBack()
{
    if (head == null) { return; }

    Node temp = head;
    temp = null;

    // over here head won't be null!
}
```

You're making both `head` and `temp` point at the same class instance and later on change `temp` to point at `null`. `head` still points at the same class instance it pointed at before.

Now, if instead of doing `temp = null` you do `temp.next = null` it is equivalent to doing `head.next = null` directly. That's because both `temp` and `head` point at the same object and you're setting a field on that object to `null`.